# I'm using Overleaf to write an article and when I try to insert a table I always get the same error: "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)."

Tags: tables, errors, multicolumn, multirow, overleaf

Does anybody know how to solve this error? Thank you in advice!

***[image: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).]***

\relax 
l.232           "
                 &" & "Mean" & "SD" & "Mean" & "SD" & "Diff." & "P-Value" \
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

[image]

Comment: The `38` is missing its unit. Should it be `38pt`, `38mm`,...?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  For future questions, it would be best to post the code as code, not as an image.  And if you can trim it down to a minimal document that should work but doesn't, then you've given us something that we can copy and paste to fix (and you may figure out the error in the process).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the specifications of the size of the column `p{38}`. the instruction is to create a column in “paragraph” mode of size 38, but unit of 38 is not specified.